# What is exact meaning of iostream is sync with ios_base::sync_with_stdio

Tags: c++, c, stdout, iostream

Is this simply means whatever we do with object like cout gets in sync with stdout (and vice versa?). What does this exactly mean. Is stdio also sync with stdout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default ostream used by std::cout and stdio(like printf) is stdout, but it is not necessarily so.

The output could alway be redirected to the other destination. Referencing this: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html

Comment: Does that mean I can output to printer like device using cout. If possible can you suggest way.

Comment: @pranitkothari Yes. The thing is to get device file descriptor and redirect cout(with a file descriptor 1) to it. You can do it in command line. The above link might give you some clue.

Answer (score 8):

If the synchronization is off, the C++ streams will be faster in some cases.

By default, all standard C++ streams are synchronized with their respective C streams.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout.sync_with_stdio(false);
    cout << "Hello\n";
    printf("World\n");
    cout << "...\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Hello
...
World
```

Changing it to `true` gives default result in order.
Output:

```
Hello
World
...
```

Comment: @POW So, can I draw conclusion, if not in sync, cout/printf cannot guarantee order or even cannot guarantee things are getting printed?

Comment: @pranitkothari not necessarily, an `endl` will change scenario even with sync turned off

Comment: @POW sure, but what about without endl I am asking. I know endl flush buffer. But what without.

Answer (score 0):

Per cppreference:

```
Sets whether the standard C++ streams are synchronized to
the standard C streams after each input/output operation.
```